# Get publickey certificate in .der format with OpenSSL in C

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to extract the publickey from a certificate using OpenSSL in C and then convert it to .der format, but I cannot manage to do it.

The goal is to extract to extract to public key to implement pinning, like here:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY.html (public key extraction)

I am using the code from [this tutorial](http://fm4dd.com/openssl/certpubkey.htm).

```
BIO *certbio = NULL;
X509 *cert = NULL;
ret = BIO_read_filename(certbio, cert_path);
cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(certbio, NULL, 0, NULL));
EVP_PKEY *pkey = X509_get_pubkey(cert));
```

How can I convert from EVP_PKEY* to an unsigned char* in .der format?
Or perhaps get it in .pem format and then convert it?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function i2d_PUBKEY() for this purpose:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/i2d_PUBKEY.html

```
 int i2d_PUBKEY(EVP_PKEY *a, unsigned char **pp);
```

Note this important statement on the man page:

> d2i_PUBKEY() and i2d_PUBKEY() decode and encode an EVP_PKEY
>   structure using SubjectPublicKeyInfo format. They otherwise follow
>   the conventions of other ASN.1 functions such as d2i_X509().

And this important note on the d2i_X509() man page:

```
int i2d_TYPE(TYPE *a, unsigned char **ppout);
```

> i2d_TYPE() encodes the structure pointed to by a into DER format.
>   If ppout is not NULL, it writes the DER encoded data to the
>   buffer at *ppout, and increments it to point after the data just
>   written. If the return value is negative an error occurred, otherwise
>   it returns the length of the encoded data.

So call it once with a NULL second parameter to discover the required length of the buffer. Call it again with a pointer to your buffer to fill in the data - but note that your pointer will be incremented afterwards (a common source of confusion).

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that the pointer is incremented afterwards - this caused some problems for us.